# jQuery Fadin in Fade Out for Multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, fading

I have an image slider that I need to fade out in order to display one of many new content blocks on hover.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting on fade out to complete before the new content is displayed.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="slider-wrapper slider">
    <!-- Slider Items -->

    <ul class="items">
        <!-- Slider One -->

        <li>
            <div class="banner">
                TEST1
            </div>
        </li><!-- Slider Two -->

        <li>
            <div class="banner">
                TEST2
            </div>
        </li><!-- Slider Three -->

        <li>
            <div class="banner">
                TEST3
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /Slider Items -->
</div>

<div id="attract-container">
    <div class="attract-copy" id="attract-slider">
        ATTTRACT CONTENT
    </div>
</div>

<div id="engage-container">
    <div class="attract-copy" id="attract-slider">
        ENGAGE CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-services a.tooltips").easyTooltip();
    $("#attract").hover(function() {
        $(".slider-wrapper").fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $("#attract-container").fadeIn(3000, function() {
                $(".slider-wrapper").hide();
            });
        });
        $("#attract-container").fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(".slider-wrapper").fadeIn(3000, function() {});
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which elements are fading in/out and in what order you expect it to happen?

Comment: got some css to go with that? also seperate your code into multiple blocks and/or make an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: for one some JS seems to be outside of the script tags... that doesn't help

Comment: well first off you don't have an element with id "attract"

Comment: here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EcXtC/2/
you're going to need to add more html or something

Comment: The code is very stripped down so ignore the misplaced script tag. The css is pretty simple the #slider-wrapper portion is displaying on load fading images in and out.  What i need to do is when I mouseover text that is in the navigation is fadeout the .slider-wrapper and fadin the the #attract-content slide.                #attract-container {
 width:950px;
 height:450px;
 padding:18px 0 0 18px;
 background:url(../images/slider-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-top:-130px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 display:none;
}

Comment: Right, which is why i am using .hover $("test").hover(function(){$(".ONE").fadeOut(100);$(".TWO").fadeIn(500);});  The problem seems to be the overlap before when the second element loads

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add in the necessary elements so we can reproduce this?  The code you have provided does not have enough information.

Comment: An accurate description, in detail, of what you want to achieve, and any examples will help/make sure you get what you want (and not what you're asking). Seems like you're doing something slightly out of your league so its not unthinkable someone will come will something entirely different that solves your problem if you explain the goal.

Comment: we'll jus t make it simple here's the page http://affinityrewards.com/new-slider.aspx mouseover the "attract"  retain and engage will need to do the same

Comment: Can you clarify what should be hidden ad then what should be shown once it fades back in?

Comment: The slider panels (.slider-wrapper) will fade out to to display a different panel not included in the slider rotation (#attract-container).

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong; normally you're showing the rotating 'banners'; but when someone hovers over the attract word it will fade out the banners container and fade in the attract container. Fade out attract word is hovered over; fade out when it leaves the container or wrapper?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from all the information you supplied I can only conclude that you're somehow trying to overcomplicate things.

Just for demonstration purposes and since it is still somewhat of a guess what you want I made this to show the effect I think you want to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Fdcw8/

A few notes about this example:

- I took the liberty to reform the html a bit but I stuck to how your html looks like but I changed id names and left out irrelevant stuff you need to move the extra/special slides into a container with the links that need to activate them.
- I used smaller sizes and none of the elaborate detail you have in the end design to display only the relevant html, css and script you need for this.
- I used a simple slider I made myself for the slides but the actual plugin used for this is irrelevant; its for display purposes.

Let me know if this is the desired effect and I will outline the steps needed to make your html work with it.

As a note; I see you're using lists which may be more semantically correct; my example could use lists too if needed but its slightly more work.

Comment: Yes, I was definitely overcomplicating things, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is both fading out and fading in the content at the same time. I'm not sure if this is what you were going for. I simplified your code to just fade out .slider-wrapper, and fade in #attract-container.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#attract").hover(function()
    {
        $(".slider-wrapper").fadeOut('fast', function ()
        {
            $("#attract-container").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have the right idea, I got that portion to work.  It's the mouseout portion that I can't seem to get right.  When I get off the #attact div I want to fade back into the slider-wrapper content.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl. To implement a mouseout, you supply a second function to hover. You also want to make sure you stop the current animation, in case it is already in the process of doing the opposite fade:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.7");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function ()
        {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#attract").hover(
                    function () {
                        $(".slider-wrapper").stop().show().fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $(".slider-wrapper").hide();
                            $("#attract-container").stop().fadeIn(3000);
                        })
                    },
                    function () {
                        $("#attract-container").stop().show().fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $("#attract-container").hide();
                            $(".slider-wrapper").stop().fadeIn(3000);
                        });
                    }
                );
            });
        });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
                <a href="#" id="attract">Hello World</a>

             <div class="slider-wrapper">

                    <div class="slider">
                        <!-- Slider Items -->
                        <ul class="items">
                            <!-- Slider One -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="banner">
                                    TEST1
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Slider Two -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="banner">
                                    TEST2
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Slider Three -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="banner">
                                    TEST3
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /Slider Items -->



                    </div>                       
                </div>

                <div id="attract-container" style="display:none">
                    <div id="attract-slider">                        
                        <div class="attract-copy">ATTTRACT CONTENT</div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="engage-container">
                    <div id="attract-slider">                        
                        <div class="attract-copy">ENGAGE CONTENT</div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can probably remove the `style="display:none"`. I'm guessing you already have that as a part of your style-sheet. I also am using Google's JQuery so that might need removed/tweaked.